# Combining PHP Heredoc with Javascript Template literals

Tags: javascript, php, heredoc, template-literals

I'm trying to use Template literals within a PHP HEREDOC segment. This causes issues with the dollar sign used in the template:

```
echo <<<JS
   console.error(`Source type ${source} not supported`);
JS;
```

Giving me the following error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: source in example.php on line 2
```

Would it be possible to avoid PHP parsing the dollar sign as a variable?

Comment: Mask it using `\$` (or use single quotes)

Comment: @ChrisG, masking with \ is just what I was looking for, thanks! The other question is not related to heredoc but has a similar solution.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an *exact* duplicate to qualify as one, as long as the other question's answers provide the knowledge needed to solve this one. The docs say that PHP's heredoc behaves just like a double quoted string, so it applies perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment by @ChrisG, simply adding a backslash solves the problem:

```
echo <<<JS
   console.error(`Source type \${source} not supported`);
JS;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Nowdoc instead of heredoc

```
$myline = 'add this line';
$input = <<<'JS'
   console.error(`Source type ${source} not supported`);
   console.log(`%s`);
JS;
$output = sprintf($input,$myline);
echo $output
```

Comment: This solves my problem for this specific row of code but I would like to keep the heredoc functionality as well!

Comment: you can generate [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) compatible string with nowdoc and then format as per your desire.

Comment: updated answer with sprintf